# How to connect a PhoneGap Mobile App to a remote MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, database, cordova, dreamweaver

I am trying to build an application for ios and android using dreamweaver and then convert it to these OS using PhoneGap.
I f there is an examples I can follow please provide me with these examples and tutorials.
I found something related to using PHP, but I don't want to use PHP.
Thank you.
Hind

Comment: You need to provide JSON data to the mobile app from the server using an URL to request it from the server. Providing the JSON data usually works with PHP on a MySQL database. For PhoneGap though you can request normal HTML code from the server, but again accessing the database you need some server script like PHP

Comment: Thank you Edwin! After some research I found some post on how to post and update data on external remote database.  http://samcroft.co.uk/2012/posting-data-from-a-phonegap-app-to-a-server-using-jquery/     ---    http://samcroft.co.uk/2010/loading-data-into-a-phonegap-app/    I hope these links could be useful to someone as it is to me.

Answer (score 2):

For Connecting with MySQL Database, you need to create a web service using PHP for JSON-based output.

1. Create MySQL Database
2. Create JSON Based Web Service using PHP / JSP / ASP whatever.
3. Use Jquery / Angular JS for GET / POST data from the web service & display them on your PhoneGap application

Read this https://codesundar.com/phonegap-php-mysql-example/ for performing CRUD operations

Comment: The link does not work. Try this: https://codesundar.com/phonegap-php-mysql-example/

Answer (score -4):

Typically, you need a server side scripting language like PHP to connect to MySQL, however for closed-source Phonegap apps, you can use http://www.mysqljs.com to connect to MySQL from Javascript using code as follows:

```
MySql.Execute(
    "mysql.yourhost.com", 
    "username", 
    "password", 
    "database", 
    "select * from Users", 
    function (data) {
        console.log(data)
});
```

It has to be mentioned that this is not suitable for website use, since the database access credentials are visible in the source code.

Comment: That is if you don't mind the folks over at http://www.mysqljs.com having your db credentials, of course. Look at what their source does: http://mysqljs.com/mysql.js